# Stomp::Error::NoCurrentConnection on my log

Tags: ruby, jruby

My log gives the error:

```
Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (NoCurrentConnection) Stomp::Error::NoCurrentConnection
    at RUBY.subscribe(/home/ubuntu/sw/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/stomp-1.2.14/lib/stomp/connection.rb:273)
    at RUBY.subscribe(/usr/share/mcollective/plugins/mcollective/connector/activemq.rb:278)
    at RUBY.subscribe(/home/ubuntu/sw/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/mcollective-client-2.2.4/lib/mcollective/util.rb:206)
    at org.jruby.RubyArray.each(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1617)
```

This is the output of `jruby -S gem list --local`:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
json (1.8.1 java)
mcollective-client (2.2.4)
rake (10.0.3)
stomp (1.2.14)
systemu (2.5.2)
```

I would like to confirm my versions of gems are correct.

Comment: I don't think you have given enough information to allow anyone to help. The error suggests that there is no connection - why do you think that is not the case? How are you establishing a connection? How are you checking that it is still connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/17384.

We also faced the issue and updated mcollective-common from 2.2.4 to 2.3.3 and the problem is solved.

Hope this helps.